# Show different options depending on what is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make it so that if United States is selected from the drop down list State list shows, if Canada is selected then the Province list shows. How can this be done?

```
<select name="country">
    <option value="US">United States</option>
    <option value="CA">Canada</option>
</select>

<select name="state">
    <option value="1">State 1</option>
    <option value="2">State 2</option>
    <option value="3">State 3</option>
</select>

<select name="province">
    <option value="1">Province 1</option>
    <option value="2">Province 2</option>
    <option value="3">Province 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JQuery, i'd recommend looking into the "change" event, combined with "show" and "hide" functions.

I won't write all the code for you, but something to the effect of;

```
$("#country").change(function()
{
    // get value of "country"
    // if it's 'US';
    $("#state").show();
    // otherwise
    $("#province").show();
});
```

It's also generally better to use id's instead of the "name" attribute, on your  elements. That enables very quick lookup of elements, and that's the only way the hash selector will work. ("#country"). If you *need* to use the "name" attribute, your selector could look like

```
$("select[name=\"country\"]")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$('select[name="country"]').change(function() {
    var val = this.value;
    if(val == "US") { 
        $('select[name="state"]').show().siblings('select[name="province"]').hide();
    } else { 
        $('select[name="province"]').show().siblings('select[name="state"]').hide();
    }
}).change();
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r5Q6G/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in plain javascript by hiding the `<select>`'s using display:none and then exposing them using an if statement in the onChange for the primary `<select>`.

```
<select name="country" onchange="if (this.value == 'CA') {    document.getElementById('state').style.display=''; } else { document.getElementById('province').style.display=''; };">
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/u7NpP/

Comment: This is actually the best implementation for what I needed but there are bugs with it... I want the default to be lets say United States so I guess States should appear right off the beginning and when you choose Canada then US the Provinces stay there they don't go away

Comment: Easy: just omit the `style='display:none;'` from the United States `<select>` and you can append extra calls in the javascript portion of the if statement just by writing them separated by semi-colons.  e.g. `document.getElementById('state').style.display='';document.getElementById('province').style.display='none';`

Comment: I changed it to this <select name="country" onchange="if (this.value == 'CA') document.getElementById('province').style.display='';document.getElementById('state').style.display='none';">

but the only problem is that if i go back to United States it won't go back to the states option

Comment: You shouldn't advocate inline javascript like that

Comment: please don't advocate inline listeners. they are a maintenance/readability nightmare.